# Elementwise aggregation (average) of values in a list of numpy arrays with same shape

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a list of numpy arrays. I want to calculate the average of values in these arrays.
For example:

```
import numpy as np
arrays = [np.random.random((4,2)) for _ in range(3)]
```

How can I have the average of elements in this array?

That is I want the results to be of shape `(4,2)` where each element is the average of corresponding indices for arrays in the list.
I know I can write a for loop to achieve this, but there should be a better numpy way.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the functional form of `np.mean`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arrays = [np.random.random((4,2)) for _ in range(3)]
>>> np.mean(arrays, axis=0)
```

This converts your list of arrays to a 3D array of shape `(3, 4, 2)` and then takes the mean along axis `0`.

You can also use Python's `sum`:

```
>>> sum(arrays)/len(arrays)
```

For small lists like your example this is actually faster.

Some timings (`m` is the length of the list):

```
m: 3   n:4   k: 2
numpy                 0.01291340 ms
python                0.00295936 ms
m: 10   n:100   k: 100
numpy                 0.14189354 ms
python                0.09465128 ms
m: 1000   n:10   k: 10
numpy                 0.43023768 ms
python                0.45201713 ms
```

Benchmarking code:

```
import numpy as np

from timeit import timeit
import types

def setup(m, n, k):
    return list(np.random.random((m, n, k)))

def f_numpy(a):
    return np.mean(a, axis=0)

def f_python(a):
    return sum(a)/len(a)

for args in [(3, 4, 2), (10, 100, 100), (1000, 10, 10)]:
    data = setup(*args)
    print('m: {}   n:{}   k: {}'.format(*args))
    for name, func in list(globals().items()):
        if not name.startswith('f_') or not isinstance(func, types.FunctionType):
            continue
        print("{:16s}{:16.8f} ms".format(name[2:], timeit(
            'f(data)', globals={'f':func, 'data':data}, number=1000)))
```

Answer (score 1):

numpy `nanmean` will ensure it to work even if some missing values are there in the data:

```
np.nanmean(arrays, axis=0)
```